# Uninterned symbols symbols

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols, gensym

There is something I can't understand about Common lisp.

Assume I'm writing a macro similar to this:

```
(defmacro test-macro () 
   (let ((result (gensym))) 
      `(let ((,result 1))
         (print (incf ,result)))))
```

Than I can do

```
> (test-macro)
2
2
```

Now I want to see how it expands

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(test-macro))
(LET ((#:G4315 1)) (PRINT (INCF #:G4315))) ;
T
```

Ok. There are unique symbols generated with gensym that were printed as uninterned.

So as far as I know the uninterned symbols are the symbols for which the evaluator does't create symbol-data binding internally.

So, if we macro-expand to that form there should be an error on (incf #:G4315).
To test this we can just evaluate that form in the REPL:

```
> (LET ((#:G4315 1)) (PRINT (INCF #:G4315)))
*** - SETQ: variable #:G4315 has no value
```

So why does the macro that expands to this string works perfectly and the form itself does not?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Symbols can be interned in a package or not.** A symbol interned in a package can be looked up and found. An uninterned symbol can't be looked up in a package. Only one symbol of a certain name can be in a package. There is only one symbol `CL-USER::FRED`.

**You write**:

> So as far as I know the uninterned symbols are the symbols for which the evaluator does't create symbol-data binding internally.

That's wrong. Uninterned symbols are symbols which are not *interned* in any package. Otherwise they are perfectly fine. *interned* means *registered* in the package's *registry* for its symbols.

The s-expression *reader* does use the symbol name and the package to identify symbols during *reading*. If there is no such symbol, it is interned. If there is one, then this one is returned.

The reader does look up symbols by their name, here in the current package:

```
 (read-from-string "FOO") -> symbol `FOO`
```

a second time:

```
 (read-from-string "FOO") -> symbol `FOO`
```

it is always the same symbol `FOO`.

```
 (eq (read-from-string "FOO") (read-from-string "FOO"))  -> T
```

`#:FOO` is the syntax for an uninterned symbol with the name `FOO`. It is not interned in any package. If the reader sees this syntax, it creates a new uninterned symbol.

```
 (read-from-string "#:FOO") -> new symbol `FOO`
```

a second time:

```
 (read-from-string "#:FOO") -> new symbol `FOO`
```

Both symbols are different. They have the same name, but they are different data objects. There is no other registry for symbols, than the packages.

```
 (eq (read-from-string "#:FOO") (read-from-string "#:FOO"))  -> NIL
```

Thus in your case `(LET ((#:G4315 1)) (PRINT (INCF #:G4315)))`, the uninterned symbols are different objects. The second one then is a different variable.

**Common Lisp has a way to print data, so that the identity is preserved during printing/reading**:

```
CL-USER 59 > (macroexpand-1 '(test-macro))
(LET ((#:G1996 1)) (PRINT (INCF #:G1996)))
T

CL-USER 60 > (setf *print-circle* t)
T

CL-USER 61 > (macroexpand-1 '(test-macro))
(LET ((#1=#:G1998 1)) (PRINT (INCF #1#)))
T
```

Now you see that the printed s-expression has a label `#1=` for the first symbol. It then later references the same variable. This can be read back and the symbol identities are preserved - even though the *reader* can't identify the symbol by looking at the package.

Thus the macro creates a form, where there is only one symbol generated. When we print that form and want to read it back, we need to make sure that the identity of uninterned symbols is preserved. Printing with `*print-circle*` set to `T` helps to do that.

**Q: Why do we use uninterned generated symbols in macros by using `GENSYM` (*generate symbol*)?**

That way we can have unique new symbols which do not clash with other symbols in the code. They get a name by the function `gensym`- usually with a counted number at the end. Since they are fresh new symbols not interned in any package, there can't be any naming conflict.

```
CL-USER 66 > (gensym)
#:G1999

CL-USER 67 > (gensym)
#:G2000

CL-USER 68 > (gensym "VAR")
#:VAR2001

CL-USER 69 > (gensym "PERSON")
#:PERSON2002

CL-USER 70 > (gensym)
#:G2003

CL-USER 71 > (describe *)

#:G2003 is a SYMBOL
NAME          "G2003"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       NIL                      <------- no package
```

Comment: If I understood your explanation correctly, `gensym` would still work correctly even if it didn't add a counted number to the name of the symbol, i.e. if it returned an uninterned symbol with the same name each time it's called (with the same argument). Is that correct? If so: why does it add the number? So that one can more easily tell which symbols are the same and which aren't in the output of `macro-expand`?

Comment: @sepp2k: correct, the number is just to make it easy to spot where uninterned symbols are different and which might be the same. It's a debugging help. In earlier Lisp dialects (without packages) it could have been more important.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The *print-circle* explanation really helpfull to understand how it works. And thanks for some explanation about unintered symbols too.

Comment: would mind changing "then the packages" to "than the packages"?

Answer (score 0):

`gensym` generate a symbol and when you print it you get the "string" representation of that symbol which isn't the same thing as "reader" representation i.e the code representation of the symbol.